# Android - Aligning button to editview slightly off

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I am wanting a button to be aligned to the the bottom and right of a EditText box.

My code is below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/global_only_available_home_delivery_postcode_check_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/global_only_available_home_delivery_postcode_check_text_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/delivery_edit_hint"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pdp_status_delivery_margin_5"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pdp_status_delivery_margin_10"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:inputType="text" />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pdp_deliverygo"
        style="@style/alternatesmallbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="35dp"
        android:minHeight="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/pdp_delivery_go"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/global_only_available_home_delivery_postcode_check_text_phone"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/global_only_available_home_delivery_postcode_check_text_phone"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is what I get [button alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBaqw.png)

As you can see from the image, the button doesn't seem to be aligned to the bottom of the textview.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have `android:layout_margin="5dp"` for the button. This assigns a margin of `5dp` to the bottom of the button and it appears as if it is not aligned to the bottom. You should **remove it** and assign margins individually to other sides if you want eg:

```
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp" // etc (optional)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pdp_deliverygo"
        style="@style/alternatesmallbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="35dp"
        android:minHeight="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/pdp_delivery_go"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"              
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/global_only_available_home_delivery_postcode_check_text_phone"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/global_only_available_home_delivery_postcode_check_text_phone"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: sadly it hasnt worked, I still get the button not aligning at the bottem. Its weird, because in the graphical view, it aligns fine, but in the app it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Try using layout_below instead of layout_alignBottom